# How to define JWT token mode for client_credentials flow in node oidc-provider

Tags: node.js, oidc-provider, node-oidc-provider

I try to use the https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider for our OAuth implementation.

There we have also some services that have to use `client_credentials` flows.
Currently we are getting an opaque Access Token but we need this as a JWT Token.

In the past > 7.x it was possible if define

```json
{
  formats: {
    ClientCredentials: 'jwt',
    AccessToken: 'jwt',
  }
}
```

But this was removed with the major version 7.x

What do we have to define to receive also for the `client_credentials` flow an `jwt` token as well?

Comment: I'm not an expert, and I might miss some things, but let me remind you, that, since JWTs are easily decodable by a third party, they should contain only public (non-secret) data, and definitely not client credentials.

Comment: As Dima said, JWTs are not encrypted. They are just encoded and should not be used to store sensitive informations. https://jwt.io/introduction A JWT **is** the authentication.